# Best way to set up notification system?

Tags: javascript, php, html, notifications

I have a CMS in php that will have internal messages. I can get notification if there is a new message when I refresh the page, but I want to get a notification when message is received (same as on facebook).

What is best way to do that?

I don't want to set a function to check for new messages every 5 min or so because database is big, and it would be best to keep processes at minimum.

Comment: I think answers to this question will be primarily opinion based.

Comment: FYI, a lot of notification systems **do** just rely on checking every X interval. Is the database query you are running huge? Even with a large database checking if there are new items in a specific table shouldn't be an unreasonable query to run.

Answer (score 2):

Look for:

- [Server-Sent events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)
- [Websockets](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270)
- [Push Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

I would say Server-Sent events are the best fit for you. Relatively easy to implement and works with older browsers.